# Não consigo fazer desaparecer cards não pedidos

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, possuo uma serie de cards que já coloquei os respectivos ids, porém quando clico na opção do menu que desejo ele apenas rola até o card com o id, mas na verdade gostaria que todos os outros desaparecessem e só os do id chamado ficassem. Podem me ajudar? :)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="list-group menu-casos" style="float: left">
            <a href="#varejo" class="list-group-item active">Varejo</a>
            <a href="#industria" class="list-group-item">Indústria</a>
            <a href="#marketing" class="list-group-item">Marketing</a>
            <a href="#seguro" class="list-group-item">Seguro</a>
            <a href="#educacao" class="list-group-item">Educação</a>
            <a href="#saude" class="list-group-item">Saúde</a>
            <a href="#financas" class="list-group-item">Finanças</a>
            <a href="#telecom" class="list-group-item">Telecom</a>
          </div>

<div class="card2 shadow" id="varejo" style="margin-top: 50px">
            <h2>E-commerce</h2>
            <pre>Texto</pre>
            <a href="#support" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba mais</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card2 shadow" id="varejo">
            <h2>Lojas Físicas</h2>
            <pre>Texto</pre>
            <a href="#support" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba mais</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card2 shadow" id="varejo">
            <h2>Serviços de Consumo</h2>
            <pre>Texto</pre>
            <a href="#support" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba mais</a>
          </div>
```

Comment: Cara vc tem que colocar o código completo ai, pelo menos de forma que de para simular o seu problema, só com esse bloco de código não da para te ajudar muito

Comment: Se você não mostrar o javascript que você está usando para alterar o comportamento da página vai ficar difícil de te ajudar.

Comment: @hugocsl Coloquei

Comment: @fernandosavio não estou usando js, apenas HTML

Comment: Sugiro fortemente que dê uma olhada no link para ter uma idéia do que consegue e não consegue fazer com Html: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML

Comment: Se você não está usando JS não tem como esperar um comportamento diferente do que o HTML provê (talvez alguma mágica com CSS, mas não é o ideal). Ou seja, você não tem nada pra alterar o comportamento padrão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só usar `:target` tipo o `href` tem que ser igual ao `id`.

Ai no CSS só o `id:target {display:block}`

```css
#varejo, 
#industria, 
#marketing {
    display: none;
}
#varejo:target , 
#industria:target , 
#marketing:target {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group menu-casos" style="float: left">
    <a href="#varejo" class="list-group-item active">Varejo</a>
    <a href="#industria" class="list-group-item">Indústria</a>
    <a href="#marketing" class="list-group-item">Marketing</a>
</div>

<div class="card2 shadow" id="varejo" style="margin-top: 50px">
    <h2>E-commerce</h2>
    <pre>Texto</pre>
    <a href="#support" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba mais</a>
</div>
<div class="card2 shadow" id="industria">
    <h2>Lojas Físicas</h2>
    <pre>Texto</pre>
    <a href="#support" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba mais</a>
</div>
<div class="card2 shadow" id="marketing">
    <h2>Serviços de Consumo</h2>
    <pre>Texto</pre>
    <a href="#support" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba mais</a>
</div>
```

Comment: A [compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) é bem decente, achei que fosse ser bem pior.

Comment: @fernandosavio sim, é uma pseudo-classe bem antiga até, e o mais legal é que não precisa ser *pai > filho*. vc pode pegar qq elemento em qq parte da tela, tipo o `for` da label para um checkbox que seria a minha dica para fazer isso e não com :target... mas como não sei a realidade do prjeto do AP vai com `:target` mesmo  :D

Comment: Interessante +1!

Comment: @LeAndrade thx

Comment: Eu conhecia a pseudo-classe há tempos... Só que na minha cabeça era uma modernidade inviável de usar atualmente. hahahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio com o IE aposentado vc pode usar praticamente o que quiser, até pq o EDGE migrou pra wibkit, os os browser modernos são todos evergreen